# Probability of picking up one ball of each color

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A box contains 6 red, 4 white and 5 black balls. A person draws 4 balls from the box at random. Let P be the probability that among the balls drawn there is at least one ball of each color. Find 455 * P.

My approach:
I reasoned that because we want at least 1 ball of each color, I could proceed like:
$\frac{6*5*4*12}{15 x 14x13x12}\quad X \quad455$

So first I can choose between the six red balls, then the 5 black balls and finally the 4 white balls. Then, since we already have 1 of each color, we choose from the remaining 12.

So with this, I got 20 as the answer. However, the answer is supposed to be 240. I understood the solution that was given, however, I wanted to know where my solution  was flawed and how I could improve it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use inclusion/exclusion principle:**

The number of ways to draw at least one ball of each color:

- Include the number of ways to draw any balls: $\binom{6+5+4}{4}=1365$
- Exclude the number of ways to draw only RB:   $\binom{6+5  }{4}= 330$
- Exclude the number of ways to draw only RW:   $\binom{6+4  }{4}= 210$
- Exclude the number of ways to draw only BW:   $\binom{5+4  }{4}= 126$
- Include the number of ways to draw only R:    $\binom{6    }{4}=  15$
- Include the number of ways to draw only B:    $\binom{5    }{4}=   5$
- Include the number of ways to draw only W:    $\binom{4    }{4}=   1$

Hence the probability to draw at least one ball of each color:

$$\frac{1365-330-210-126+15+5+1}{1365}=\frac{48}{91}$$

**Multiplying this by $455$ will give you the desired result of $240$.**

Comment: I understand your solution, but is there a way my method can lead to the solution?

Comment: @coolcheetah: When you "choose from the remaining $12$", you are double counting combinations (and I'm using the term "double counting" as simple way of saying "multi counting").

Comment: Could you please explain how I am double counting? I think that'd help me in the future.

Comment: @coolcheetah: By choosing the exact same combination several times For example, in one combination you choose red ball #1 in your first step and red ball #2 in your second step, and in another combination you choose red ball #2 in your first step and red ball #1 in your second step.

Comment: But if you understand the solution that was given to you then my answer is irrelevant to your question and I will delete it.

Comment: So is there any way I could remedy the double counting?

Comment: @coolcheetah: Not that I can see (unless you're willing to replace it altogether).

Comment: Hmmm...so I guess this approach won't work. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @coolcheetah: You're welcome :)

Comment: Why do we include the number of ways to draw only R, B and W? Shouldn't it be excluded since it doesn't lead to a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I find this method much simpler.

Red-white-black need to be drawn in 2-1-1 ,1-2-1 or 1-1-2 pattern, so simply apply the hypergeometric formula:

$$455\times \dfrac{{6\choose 2}{4\choose 1}{5\choose1}+{6\choose 1}{4\choose2}{5\choose 1} +{6\choose1}{4\choose 1}{5\choose 2}}{15\choose 4} = 240$$

*NOTE*

Make a note that whenever you try to "fractionate" the combinations, by fulfilling the conditions in instalments the way you did, you will always overcount.

Answer (score 1):

We can still proceed ahead from the way you counted $ 6*5*4*12 = 1440 $ & subtract the duplicates. For example duplicates for:
Red balls $$ \binom{6}{2} * 5 *4 = 300 $$
for Black balls $$ \binom{5}{2} * 6 *4 = 240 $$
for White balls $$ \binom{4}{2} * 6 *5 = 180 $$

so net $1440-300-240-180 = 720$ out of a total of $\binom {15}{4} = 1365$ giving $ P= 720/1365$ and $455* P =240.$